# How to create the windows service for existing domain in glassfish

Tags: windows, service, glassfish

I want to create windows service for existing in Sun Glassfish v2 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Refer the following url :

         http://technicallearning.wordpress.com/category/glassfish/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GlassfishSvc](http://www.ryandelaplante.com/2009/08/in-past-i-have-chosen-to-use-commercial.html), it allows creating a windows service with a name of your choice. We've been using it for almost 2 years and are very happy with it